# Get the status of a checkbox from a Custom List in Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying a custom List item based on the KivyMD's documentation [examples](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/#custom-list-item), but I'm having a problem identifying which of my chechkboxes has been activated.
With `* args` I can access its state and which object it is but it prints like this:
`{<__ main __. RightCheckbox object at 0x000001B1A62E6970>`, `False}`.

The problem is that `"0x000001B1A62E6970"` is not a constant value *(this value may change with the execution of the code)* that represents the checkbox as its **id** does.

**My minimal code KV:**

```
KV = '''
MDCard:
    orientation : 'vertical'
    size_hint : (0.8,0.3)
    pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
    elevation : 15
    padding : 20
    spacing : 30
    id: box
    MDList:
        id: scroll

<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox: 
'''
```

**And the MainApp and Custom Class definitions:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons

class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''
    icon = StringProperty("android")

    def on_press(self):
        print(self.text)

class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''

    def on_active(self, *args):
        print(args)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        for i in range(5):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", icon=icons[i])
            )

MainApp().run()
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to give a default id for the RightCheckbox to later change it to a unique one when putting the widgets in the list and thus access their states in something like "root.ids.checkboxid" but I don't know how to put it when doing `self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget (ListItemWithCheckbox (text = f "Item {i}", icon = icons [i]))`

Also in the on_active method *(when any checkbox is selected)* of the `RightCheckbox` class I have tried to print various attributes such as `MDCheckBox.active .icon .ids. .text` but none of them prints anything to help me identify which specific checkbox has been selected

I would really appreciate if anyone can help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a reference to the `ListItemWithCheckbox` within the `RightCheckbox` like this:

```
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox: 
        listItem: root
```

Then your `on_active()` method can use that reference:

```
class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''

    def on_active(self, rcb, value):
        print(rcb.listItem.text, 'is', value)
```

Comment: Your answer works perfect. I really did not know that you could assign a custom value different from the ones defined by default MDCheckbox, I will see if it is possible to suggest adding your answer to the documentation to complement the example.